# How can I create a new id for every new comment while making sure it doesn't conflict with other comments fetched from the Api using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a small blog that fetches data from an API. The API returns an array of objects with each object include the post and sometimes another object containing comments and the ID of that particular comment. How can I collect the used IDs so when I add another comment it is unique and not one already used?

Example of the data that is fetched:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": "111",
      "title": "How do like them apples?",
      "text": "Lorem ipsum elit ante aliquam blandit nulla gravida, elementum sollicitudin ipsum litora rhoncus urna, nec in pulvinar quam libero dictumst. Duis hac augue auctor sed proin senectus ante purus est, condimentum mattis nostra non porttitor sit nibh ornare etiam quisque eros ultricies eget taciti inceptos etiam ornare feugiat pretium. Varius ullamcorper imperdiet tortor quisque odio ullamcorper pulvinar, tortor semper primis consequat libero erat, adipiscing mi donec semper duis magna.",
      "author": "simon",
      "category": "mobile",
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "author": "shaun",
          "text": "Lorem ipsum varius senectus nostra lectus nunc sollicitudin."
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "author": "william",
          "text": "aliquam blandit nulla gravida"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "112",
      "title": "The new normal....",
      "text": "Lorem ipsum molestie inceptos ullamcorper vel faucibus curae amet, lacinia et euismod tempus fringilla blandit litora risus in, accumsan mollis netus leo posuere adipiscing aliquam.Nibh nunc volutpat integer class mollis tellus cubilia, quisque elit proin sagittis netus cubilia, per aenean neque est dictum phasellus sapien eget fringilla ligula hac nostra platea.",
      "author": "william",
      "category": "mobile",
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "author": "shaun",
          "text": "lacinia et euismod tempus fringilla blandit"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to solve this? What does your array look like? Please, add some code or some example of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an array of 'ids' in your Vue data, like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    ...
    data:{
        ids : []
    }
})
```

and after getting the objects from the API you should check if it already exists:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    ...
    methods:{
        getPosts: function() { ... },
        insertId: function(id){
         if(this.ids.includs(id)){
             //handle the duplicate id
         }
    }
})
```